# SwiftUI Picker will not allow me to select items

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to use the Picker in my SwiftUI view. I want radio buttons. Everything looks as I want it to however the only problem that I am having is that the Picker will not allow me to select anything. I added the .tag modifier however it's not allowing me to pick anything and I am not sure how to fix it.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SubscriptionView: View {
    @State private var selectedProduct: SubscriptionProduct?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Text("Choose a Subscription Plan")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            
            Picker("", selection: $selectedProduct) {
                SubscriptionOptionView(product: .monthly).tag(SubscriptionProduct.monthly)
                SubscriptionOptionView(product: .annually).tag(SubscriptionProduct.annually)
            }
            .pickerStyle(.inline)
            .frame(height: 40)
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
            )
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .padding(.vertical, 10) // Adjust the vertical spacing here
            
            if let selectedProduct = selectedProduct {
                Text("Selected Plan: \(selectedProduct.rawValue)")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.green)
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                // Handle subscription purchase
                if let selectedProduct = selectedProduct {
                    purchaseSubscription(product: selectedProduct)
                } else {
                    // Show an alert or error message indicating no product selected
                }
            }) {
                Text("Subscribe")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    func purchaseSubscription(product: SubscriptionProduct) {
        // Add your subscription purchase logic here
        switch product {
        case .monthly:
            // Handle monthly subscription purchase
            break
        case .annually:
            // Handle annual subscription purchase
            break
        }
    }
}

struct SubscriptionOptionView: View {
    let product: SubscriptionProduct
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(product.rawValue)
                .font(.headline)
                .fontWeight(.regular)
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
            
            Spacer()
            
            Text(product.priceText)
                .font(.subheadline)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        }
    }
}

enum SubscriptionProduct: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case monthly = "Monthly Subscription"
    case annually = "Annual Subscription"
    
    var id: String { self.rawValue }
    
    var priceText: String {
        switch self {
        case .monthly:
            return "$2.99"
        case .annually:
            return "$30.89"
        }
    }
}

struct SubscriptionView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SubscriptionView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. Your `@State` variable needs to match the type of your tag (right now, the `@State` is `Optional` and the tag isn't). One option is to make the `@State` non-Optional and set a default value:

```
@State private var selectedProduct: SubscriptionProduct = .monthly
```

Or, you can make the `tag`s `Optional`:

```
SubscriptionOptionView(product: .monthly).tag(Optional(SubscriptionProduct.monthly))
SubscriptionOptionView(product: .annually).tag(Optional(SubscriptionProduct.annually))
```

2. You're setting a `frame` on the `Picker` that doesn't allow the whole thing to be shown. It's really a wheel, but you can't see that, so it looks like the UI can't be interacted with. Perhaps you meant `menu`? Or, remove the `frame`